# Are there infinitely many primes of the form $(3^{n} - 1)/2$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

I've been trying to show that there are infinitely many primes in the form of
$$ \frac {3^n - 1}{2}$$

Up until now I've tried a modified version Euclid's way of proving the infinity of primes but didn't find a solid answer. Do you have a particular way of approaching this problem? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Given that we don't know the same for $2^n-1$, it is unlikely that we know it for $(3^n-1)/2$, unless it is in the negative. We also don't know it for $(10^n-1)/9$ - the repunit primes. Basically, this is a hard sort of problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prime numbers of the form $(3^n-1)/2$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/454398/prime-numbers-of-the-form-3n-1-2)

Comment: Not at all a duplicate.  This is asking if there are infinite primes in the form.  The other is to show some of the non-primes in the form.