How to find finite fields of prime power order with two multiplicative subgroups of order $2$ and an odd prime $q$?
I want to find finite fields of prime power order $p^n$ that have only two multiplicative subgroups of order $2$ and a large prime $q$. In particular, I need an odd prime $p$ and an integer $n>1$ such that $p^n-1=2q$ for some odd prime $q$. A quick implementation shows that in the first $1024$ odd primes and for $1<n\le2^{16}$, the only prime that satisfies this relation is $p=3$ with $n\in\{3,7,13,71,103,541,1091,1367,1627\}$. But I need finite fields of larger size.
My question is how to find out such primes $p$ (with $n$) analytically? Is there any classification of primes that satisfy this relation?

that have only two subgroups - $\Bbb F_q$ has an additive and a multiplicative group. Which one do you mean?

@DietrichBurde I mean multiplicative subgroups.

We want primes $p$ and $q$ to satisfy
$$p^n-1=2q$$
Suppose $p>2$. Let $A$ be the number $2q$. Since $2$ and $q$ are both primes, then $A$ has exactly $4$ divisors: $1,2,q,A$. Factoring the left hand side we have:
$$(p-1)(1+p+p^2+\dots+p^{n-1}) =2q=A$$
This implies $(p-1) | A $, but $(p-1)=1$ is impossible since $p>2$, and $(p-1)=A$ is impossible since $(1+p+p^2+\dots+p^{n-1})>1$.
Then the only possibilities are $(p-1)=2$, that results in $p=3$, and $(p-1)=q$, that again results in $p=3$.
Therefore $p=3$ is the largest prime that you will find satisfying your condition.

Thank you so much for this excellent proof. Could you also put some insight on the upper-bound on $n$, kindly? I need larger fields. Until when $n$ makes the number $(1+3+3^2+\cdots+3^{n-1})$ a prime?

You might wanna look at this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/454398/1174256 . It says that your number $q$ can be prime only if $n$ is prime.

Thank you from the bottom of my heart. Yes, this is exactly what I was talking about.
